# What is the probability of observing a decreasing sequence of Gaussian random variables?

Tags: probability

The probability of observing a decreasing sequence of $k$ i.i.d. Gaussian random variables is $1/n!$.  This is  shown by computing

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{\infty}^{x1} \cdots \int_{\infty}^{x_{n-1}} f(\mathbf{x}) \, dx_n \, dx_{n-1} \cdots dx_1 $$

Here, $f$ is a multivariate Gaussian density.  Suppose now I am interested in computing the probability of observing a  decreasing sequence of length $k$ of Gaussian random variables in a larger sequence of $n$.  To be clear, the sequence of decreasing terms must be consecutive. The following sequence
$$ 0,1.9, 1.8, 0.4, 0, -0.4, 1$$

sees a decreasing sequence of length 5 in a sequence of length 7.  Note that the decreasing terms are all consecutive.

How can I compute this probability?  Is the result presented at the beginning  of this post useful?

Comment: Do the numbers have to be consecutive in the sequence?

Comment: @Bartek Yes.  To clarify, the numbers must be consecutively decreasing.  I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$, we can reorder them such that $X_{i_1}< X_{i_2} < ... < X_{i_n}$, where $i_1,i_2,...,i_n$ is a permutation of $1,2,...,n$. The index number $k$ satisfying $X_j=X_{i_k}$ is called the rank of $X_j$ and we denote it $R_j$.

$R_1,R_2,...,R_n$ are again random variables. The vector $R=(R_1,...,R_n)$ is always a permutation of $1,...,n$, and since we have i.i.d. variables it turns out that all permutations are equally likely, that is for any permutation $r$, we have $P(R=r)=\frac{1}{n!}$.

In particular $P(R=(n,n-1,n-2,...,1))=\frac{1}{n!}$, which indeed is the probability of observing a decreasing sequence.

Note that the this result has nothing to do with the normal distribution. The only assumptions needed on $X_1,...,X_n$ are that they are continous i.i.d. variables. This means that your problem is entirely a combinatorical problem. To calculate the probability you must count the number of permutations of $1,...,7$, which has a decreasing sequence of length 5, and then divide that number by $7!$.

Comment: That's brilliant!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the previous answer, the numbers you are looking for are the elements of the triangle described in OEIS A008304 divided by the respective factorial. So for $n=1$ we have $p=1$ for $k=1$. For $n=2$ we have $p=\frac{1}{2}$ for $k=1$ and $k=2$. For $n=3$ the probabilities are $\frac{1}{6}$, $\frac{4}{6}$, $\frac{1}{6}$ for $k=1$, $2$ and $3$ respectively and so on as described on the OEIS. The specific probability of getting decreasing subsequence of consecutive elements and length $5$ among $7$ random numbers is $\frac{99}{7!}=\frac{11}{560} \approx 1.96\%$.